# Ruby Style: How to check whether a nested hash element exists

Tags: ruby, hash, coding-style

Consider a "person" stored in a hash. Two examples are:

```
fred = {:person => {:name => "Fred", :spouse => "Wilma", :children => {:child => {:name => "Pebbles"}}}}
slate = {:person => {:name => "Mr. Slate", :spouse => "Mrs. Slate"}}
```

If the "person" doesn't have any children, the "children" element is not present. So, for Mr. Slate, we can check whether he has parents:

```
slate_has_children = !slate[:person][:children].nil?
```

So, what if we don't know that "slate" is a "person" hash? Consider:

```
dino = {:pet => {:name => "Dino"}}
```

We can't easily check for children any longer:

```
dino_has_children = !dino[:person][:children].nil?
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

So, how would you check the structure of a hash, especially if it is nested deeply (even deeper than the examples provided here)? Maybe a better question is: What's the "Ruby way" to do this?

Comment: Any reason why you haven't implemented an object model for this or at least decorated some structs with validation methods. I think you'll drive yourself nuts trying to add semantics onto a hash.

Comment: Even if you have an object model, you need sometimes to extract data from a hash to populate your model. For example if you get data from a JSON stream.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The most obvious way to do this is to simply check each step of the way:

```
has_children = slate[:person] && slate[:person][:children]
```

Use of .nil? is really only required when you use false as a placeholder value, and in practice this is rare. Generally you can simply test it exists.

> **Update**: If you're using Ruby 2.3 or later  there's a built-in [`dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-dig) method that does what's described in this answer.

If not, you can also define your own Hash "dig" method which can simplify this substantially:

```
class Hash
  def dig(*path)
    path.inject(self) do |location, key|
      location.respond_to?(:keys) ? location[key] : nil
    end
  end
end
```

This method will check each step of the way and avoid tripping up on calls to nil. For shallow structures the utility is somewhat limited, but for deeply nested structures I find it's invaluable:

```
has_children = slate.dig(:person, :children)
```

You might also make this more robust, for example, testing if the :children entry is actually populated:

```
children = slate.dig(:person, :children)
has_children = children && !children.empty?
```

Comment: How would you go about using the same method for setting values in the nested hash?

Comment: You'd have to write something that creates the intermediate hashes instead of simply testing if they're there. `location[key] ||= { }` would be sufficient if you're dealing with hashes only but you'd have to extract the last part `final_key = path.pop` and assign to it in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This is how I solved the problem, I used the same inject method on the path, but put this in it's block instead.
`location[key] = ( location[key].class == Hash ) ? location[key] : value`

Comment: You can also use the `is_a?` method which is more concise: `location[key].is_a?(Hash)` but this would exclude hash-like objects that sometimes come into play.

Comment: is_a?(hash) - good idea. keeping it short concise and simple :p

Comment: Where is the pluralization (:keys) coming from? I'm only aware of the Rails Inflector module..

Comment: `:keys` is a method that Hash provides and is (usually) a reliable enough indicator of the object in question being a Hash or Hash equivalent.

Comment: Many thanks ! by removing splat operator (*) from method argument you can pass string as parameter ex.: `dig "path/path/path/path".split('/')`

Comment: You can still do that without changing the method signature. Call it like `dig(*("a/b/c".split('/')))` instead. An alternative would be to iterate using `path.flatten.inject` to handle array arguments.

Comment: `is_a? Hash` should be faster since `respond_to?` has to traverse the methods on the object.  Also, -1000 for encouraging monkey patching.  Wrap/extend the Hash class, or create a Hash utility class and pass the hash under test into the method instead of monkey patching onto the Ruby Hash class.  Monkey Patching is the main reason Chef needed to write their own dependency installer.

Comment: @Josiah If you've got a problem with extending core classes, better steer clear of Rails completely, it's endemic there. Used sparingly this is can make your code a lot cleaner. Used aggressively leads to chaos.

Comment: @tadman this is one of my misgivings about Ruby. I love the language and the enthusiasm of the community, but the community's tendancy to monkey patch here and there creates headaches.  I put up with it in Rails, though I don't agree with it.

Comment: @tadman fyi through this SO answer, #dig is now in Ruby trunk: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/11/11/ruby-2-3-0-preview1-released/ :D

Comment: @GabeKopley Wow, that's great news. I've found this function to be really helpful and I'm glad it's going mainstream now.

Answer (score 25):

With Ruby 2.3 we'll have support for the safe navigation operator:
https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/11/11/ruby-2-3-0-preview1-released/

`has_children` now could be written as:

```
has_children = slate[:person]&.[](:children)
```

`dig` is being added as well:

```
has_children = slate.dig(:person, :children)
```

Comment: If you are using Ruby < 2.3, I just published a gem that adds the 2.3-compatible Hash#dig and Array#dig methods:

https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_dig

Answer (score 13):

Another alternative:

```
dino.fetch(:person, {})[:children]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `andand` gem:

```
require 'andand'

fred[:person].andand[:children].nil? #=> false
dino[:person].andand[:children].nil? #=> true
```

You can find further explanations at http://andand.rubyforge.org/.

Answer (score 2):

One could use hash with default value of {} - empty hash. For example,

```
dino = Hash.new({})
dino[:pet] = {:name => "Dino"}
dino_has_children = !dino[:person][:children].nil? #=> false
```

That works with already created Hash as well:

```
dino = {:pet=>{:name=>"Dino"}}
dino.default = {}
dino_has_children = !dino[:person][:children].nil? #=> false
```

Or you can define [] method for nil class

```
class NilClass
  def [](* args)
     nil
   end
end

nil[:a] #=> nil
```

Comment: You would have to ensure that .default is nested deep into every hash.

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying the above answers here:

Create a Recursive Hash method whose value cannot be nil, like as follows.

```
def recursive_hash
  Hash.new {|key, value| key[value] = recursive_hash}
end

> slate = recursive_hash 
> slate[:person][:name] = "Mr. Slate"
> slate[:person][:spouse] = "Mrs. Slate"

> slate
=> {:person=>{:name=>"Mr. Slate", :spouse=>"Mrs. Slate"}}
slate[:person][:state][:city]
=> {}
```

If you don't mind creating empty hashes if the value does not exists for the key :)

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, you really had to do something like this:

```
structure[:a] && structure[:a][:b]
```

However, Ruby 2.3 added a feature that makes this way more graceful:

```
structure.dig :a, :b # nil if it misses anywhere along the way
```

There is a gem called `ruby_dig` that will back-patch this for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
def flatten_hash(hash)
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
    if v.is_a? Hash
      flatten_hash(v).map do |h_k, h_v|
        h["#{k}_#{h_k}"] = h_v
      end
    else
      h[k] = v
    end
  end
end

irb(main):012:0> fred = {:person => {:name => "Fred", :spouse => "Wilma", :children => {:child => {:name => "Pebbles"}}}}
=> {:person=>{:name=>"Fred", :spouse=>"Wilma", :children=>{:child=>{:name=>"Pebbles"}}}}

irb(main):013:0> slate = {:person => {:name => "Mr. Slate", :spouse => "Mrs. Slate"}}
=> {:person=>{:name=>"Mr. Slate", :spouse=>"Mrs. Slate"}}

irb(main):014:0> flatten_hash(fred).keys.any? { |k| k.include?("children") }
=> true

irb(main):015:0> flatten_hash(slate).keys.any? { |k| k.include?("children") }
=> false
```

This will flatten all the hashes into one and then any? returns true if any key matching the substring "children" exist.
This might also help.

Comment: I gave a thought on @zeeraw 's comment to use is_a? for a nested hash and came up with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
dino_has_children = !dino.fetch(person, {})[:children].nil?
```

Note that in rails you can also do:

```
dino_has_children = !dino[person].try(:[], :children).nil?   #
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do a deep check for any falsy values in the hash and any nested hashes without monkey patching the Ruby Hash class (PLEASE don't monkey patch on the Ruby classes, such is something you should not do, EVER).

(Assuming Rails, although you could easily modify this to work outside of Rails)

```
def deep_all_present?(hash)
  fail ArgumentError, 'deep_all_present? only accepts Hashes' unless hash.is_a? Hash

  hash.each do |key, value|
    return false if key.blank? || value.blank?
    return deep_all_present?(value) if value.is_a? Hash
  end

  true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play with

```
dino.default = {}
```

Or for example:

```
empty_hash = {}
empty_hash.default = empty_hash

dino.default = empty_hash
```

That way you can call

```
empty_hash[:a][:b][:c][:d][:e] # and so on...
dino[:person][:children] # at worst it returns {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
x = {:a => {:b => 'c'}}
y = {}
```

you could check *x* and *y* like this:

```
(x[:a] || {})[:b] # 'c'
(y[:a] || {})[:b] # nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Thks @tadman for the answer.

For those who want perfs (and are stuck with ruby < 2.3), this method is 2.5x faster:

```
unless Hash.method_defined? :dig
  class Hash
    def dig(*path)
      val, index, len = self, 0, path.length
      index += 1 while(index < len && val = val[path[index]])
      val
    end
  end
end
```

and if you use [RubyInline](https://github.com/seattlerb/rubyinline), this method is 16x faster:

```
unless Hash.method_defined? :dig
  require 'inline'

  class Hash
    inline do |builder|
      builder.c_raw '
      VALUE dig(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self) {
        rb_check_arity(argc, 1, UNLIMITED_ARGUMENTS);
        self = rb_hash_aref(self, *argv);
        if (NIL_P(self) || !--argc) return self;
        ++argv;
        return dig(argc, argv, self);
      }'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a module to alias the brackets methods and use the Ruby syntax to read/write nested elements.

#### UPDATE: Instead of overriding the bracket accessors, request Hash instance to extend the module.

```
module Nesty
  def []=(*keys,value)
    key = keys.pop
    if keys.empty? 
      super(key, value) 
    else
      if self[*keys].is_a? Hash
        self[*keys][key] = value
      else
        self[*keys] = { key => value}
      end
    end
  end

  def [](*keys)
    self.dig(*keys)
  end
end

class Hash
  def nesty
    self.extend Nesty
    self
  end
end
```

Then you can do:

```
irb> a = {}.nesty
=> {}
irb> a[:a, :b, :c] = "value"
=> "value"
irb> a
=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>"value"}}}
irb> a[:a,:b,:c]
=> "value"
irb> a[:a,:b]
=> {:c=>"value"}
irb> a[:a,:d] = "another value"
=> "another value"
irb> a
=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>"value"}, :d=>"another value"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how "Ruby" it is(!), but the [KeyDial](https://github.com/ConvincibleMedia/ruby-gem-key_dial) gem which I wrote lets you do this basically without changing your original syntax:

```
has_kids = !dino[:person][:children].nil?
```

becomes:

```
has_kids = !dino.dial[:person][:children].call.nil?
```

This uses some trickery to intermediate the key access calls. At `call`, it will try to `dig` the previous keys on `dino`, and if it hits an error (as it will), returns nil. `nil?` then of course returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `&` and `key?` it is O(1) compared to  `dig` which is O(n) and this will make sure person is accessed without `` NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass ``

```
fred[:person]&.key?(:children) //=>true
slate[:person]&.key?(:children)
```