# Detect if XML node exists in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

Is there a simple way to detect if an XML node exists in Rails?

To get the @result instance variable I use

```
response, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, params)
@result = Hash.from_xml(response.body)
```

I've tried:

```
if @result['GetProperties']['Errors'].exists?
```

or just

```
if @result['GetProperties']['Errors']
```

but both result in the following error:

**undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**

**I should make clear that I have no problem parsing XML - I just need to know how to detect if a node exists**

Comment: You must add more details. Either `@result` is nil or `@result['GetProperties']` is. Once you have your XML, drop it into `Nokogiri::XML()`, and use `xpath_at` to get the nodes.

Comment: What XML parser/library are you using? What is `@result?` etc.

Comment: not using any specific parser at the moment - should I be doing?

Comment: edited my question to show you what `@result` is

Comment: Your code still doesn't say if `@result` or `@result['GetProperties']` has the `nil`. And I'd trust Nokogiri more than `Hash.from_xml`, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Given your additional info - something like this would work:

```
if @result && @result['GetProperties'] && @result['GetProperties']['Errors']
```

If `Hash.from_xml` doesn't ever return `nil`, (just check the doc on this one, I don't personally know) you could simplify it to:

```
if @result['GetProperties'] && @result['GetProperties']['Errors']
```

Finally, if you think that's kind of sloppy, you could consider writing a method of some sort to check for nested properties all at once like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1820492/3124288