# How do I use Array#dig and Hash#dig introduced in Ruby 2.3?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, splat

Ruby 2.3 introduces a new method on `Array` and `Hash` called `dig`. The examples I've seen in blog posts about the new release are contrived and convoluted:

```
# Hash#dig
user = {
  user: {
    address: {
      street1: '123 Main street'
    }
  }
}

user.dig(:user, :address, :street1) # => '123 Main street'

# Array#dig
results = [[[1, 2, 3]]]
results.dig(0, 0, 0) # => 1
```

I'm not using triple-nested flat arrays. What's a realistic example of how this would be useful?

**UPDATE**

It turns out these methods solve one of the most commonly-asked Ruby questions. The questions below have something like 20 duplicates, all of which are solved by using `dig`:

[How to avoid NoMethodError for missing elements in nested hashes, without repeated nil checks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371716/how-to-avoid-nomethoderror-for-missing-elements-in-nested-hashes-without-repeat)

[Ruby Style: How to check whether a nested hash element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820451/ruby-style-how-to-check-whether-a-nested-hash-element-exists)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In our case, `NoMethodError`s due to `nil` references are by far the most common errors we see in our production environments.

The new `Hash#dig` allows you to omit `nil` checks when accessing nested elements. Since hashes are best used for when the structure of the data is unknown, or volatile, having official support for this makes a lot of sense.

Let's take your example. The following:

```
user.dig(:user, :address, :street1)
```

Is **not** equivalent to:

```
user[:user][:address][:street1]
```

In the case where `user[:user]` or `user[:user][:address]` is `nil`, this will result in a runtime error.

Rather, it is equivalent to the following, which is the current idiom:

```
user[:user] && user[:user][:address] && user[:user][:address][:street1]
```

Note how it is trivial to pass a list of symbols that was created elsewhere into `Hash#dig`, whereas it is not very straightforward to recreate the latter construct from such a list. `Hash#dig` allows you to easily do dynamic access without having to worry about `nil` references.

Clearly `Hash#dig` is also a lot shorter.

---

One important point to take note of is that `Hash#dig` itself returns `nil` if any of the keys turn out to be, which can lead to the same class of errors one step down the line, so it can be a good idea to provide a sensible default. (This way of providing an object which always responds to the methods expected is called the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#Ruby).)

Again, in your example, an empty string or something like "N/A", depending on what makes sense:

```
user.dig(:user, :address, :street1) || ""
```

Comment: I wish there was a `Hash#dig!` which would do the equivalent of multiple #fetch's.

Comment: @Dogweather: You can try submitting a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk), and see if someone picks it up. :-)

Comment: Alternative idioms sometimes seen are `arr.fetch(:user, {}).fetch(:address, {})[:street1]` and for Rails, `arr[:user].try(:[], :address).try(:[], :street1)`.

Comment: @Drenmi are there possible instances where it is still preferable to use the old [:a][:b] syntax over dig, given I need to access a chain of keys down a hash?

Comment: @MartinVerdejo: The only reason I can think of is if you're working on a code base that needs to maintain backwards compatibility with earlier rubies.

Comment: @matthew.tuck you need to be careful chaining `fetch` calls like that. If for example `arr = { user: nil }` will blow up with `NoMethodError: undefined method fetch for nil:NilClass`

Comment: You have to be careful with `user.dig(:user, :address, :street1) || ""`, if the dig result was boolean `false`, it'll be turned into empty string.

Comment: Is there an `Array#something` where `a[b][c][d]` is equivalent to `a.something([b, c, d])`? I could really use something like that right now.

Answer (score 12):

One way would be in conjunction with the splat operator reading from some unknown document model.

```
some_json = JSON.parse( '{"people": {"me": 6, ... } ...}' )
# => "{"people" => {"me" => 6, ... }, ... }
a_bunch_of_args = response.data[:query]
# => ["people", "me"]
some_json.dig(*a_bunch_of_args)
# => 6
```

Answer (score 2):

It's useful for working your way through deeply nested Hashes/Arrays, which might be what you'd get back from an API call, for instance.

*In theory* it saves a ton of code that would otherwise check at each level whether another level exists, without which you risk constant errors. *In practise* you still may need a lot of this code as `dig` will still create errors in some cases (e.g. if anything in the chain is a non-keyed object.)

It is for this reason that your question is actually really valid - `dig` hasn't seen the usage we might expect. This is commented on here for instance: [Why nobody speaks about dig](http://anamaria.martinezgomez.name/2018/01/07/ruby-dig.html).

To make `dig` avoid these errors, try the [KeyDial](https://github.com/ConvincibleMedia/ruby-gem-key_dial) gem, which I wrote to wrap around `dig` and force it to return nil/default if any error crops up.