# How to access nested attributes in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, nested-attributes

I want to access usr_additional_users_attributes in the following params? how can i do that ?

```
 params.require(:usr_contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :dob, :gender,
                                    :mobile, :email, :password,
                                    :password_confirmation,
                                    :image,
                                    usr_contact_vendors_attributes:
                                        [:id, usr_vendor_property_attributes:
                                            [:shop_name, :specified_area, :mobile, :website,
                                             usr_vendor_branches_attributes:
                                                 [:address_line1, :address_line2, :city ,:zip_code ],
                                             usr_additional_users_attributes:[:id,:email,:role, :_destroy]]] )
```

end

I want to get it like this in my controller and put emails to an array. this one showing an error

```
 params[:usr_contact][:usr_contact_vendors_attributes][:usr_vendor_property_attributes][:usr_additional_users_attributes].values.each do |item|
      @emailSet << item[:email]
    end
```

**undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**

any suggestions ?

Comment: I would say, go step by step to check `params[:usr_contact]`, then `params[:usr_contact][:usr_contact_vendors_attributes]`, and so on. One of these is `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use [dig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34348418/289657) because when you're trying to access one of these params, they're null, so Ruby raise this exception. By using `dig`, it's like it's checking every attribute before you're accessing it. It would be good to check inside the item too with `item[:email].present?`

Your code would look like:

```
 params.dig(:usr_contact, :usr_contact_vendors_attributes, :usr_vendor_property_attributes, :usr_additional_users_attributes).values.each do |item|
   @emailSet << item[:email] if item[:email].present?
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an example of how I did it in my scenario:

```
def patient_params
    params.require(:patient).permit(*permited_patient_attributes)
  end

  def permited_patient_attributes
    [
      :user_id,
      :start,
      patient_demographic_attributes: [
        :id,
        :patient_id,
        :start_date,
        :end_date,
        :first_name,
        :middle_name,
        :last_name,
        :date_of_birth,
        :gender,
        :ethnicity,
        :marital_status],
      patient_contact_attributes: [
        :id,
        :patient_id,
        :street_address,
        :extended_address,
        :locality,
        :region,
        :postal_code,
        :country],
      patient_email_attributes: [
        :id,
        :email],
      patient_mrn_attributes: [
        :id,
        :patient_id,
        :mrn],
      contact_telephones_attributes: [
        :id,
        :party_type,
        :party_id,
        :name,
        :number,
        :_destroy],
      patient_physicians_attributes: [
        :id,
        :patient_id,
        physician_id: []]
    ]
  end
```

Here patient_demographic_attributes,  patient_contact_attributes. are nested one.Have a try

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your `item` is not nil before pushing it to your array. Easiest way is to do this is by adding a check if `item` is nil.

```
@emailSet << item[:email] unless item.nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by printing params. It was something like this

```
{"0"=>{"usr_vendor_property_attributes"=>{"shop_name"=>"cbhcvbcvb", "specified_area"=>"cbcvbcb", "website"=>"bcbc@gmail.com", "mobile"=>"3543243", "usr_vendor_branches_attributes"=>{"1493800739760"=>{"address_line1"=>"", "address_line2"=>"", "city"=>"", "zip_code"=>""}}, "usr_additional_users_attributes"=>{"1493800739774"=>{"email"=>"sdgdfgd", "role"=>"Role1", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}}} permitted: false>
```

I have miss that ["0"], that was the issue. 
Then params can access in the controller like this.

```
 @test = params[:usr_contact][:usr_contact_vendors_attributes]["0"][:usr_vendor_property_attributes][:usr_additional_users_attributes]
```

Thanks for helping  :D

Comment: Yes, but if one of the params in the middle is nil, it will raise an error.