# Rspec: unit testing for the merge! method in Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a piece of code which has:

```
requests.each do |request|
  request.each do |rqst|
    select_keys = ["author", "author_name"]
    selected_unit_req = rqst.select { |m| select_keys.include?(m) }
    user = Etl::Models::User.where(username: selected_unit_req["author"]["username"] )
    user.merge!({ author_name: selected_unit_req["author"]["name"] })
  end
end
```

I am unable to test the merge! method , getting `NoMethodError:undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` when I run my existing unit tests. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you write a test for another (builtin) class's methods? And from a style perspective, [avoid using `{}` for multi-line blocks](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#single-line-blocks). Trying to decipher your example is making my head hurt.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I run my unit tests.   `NoMethodError:
       undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Your example is way, way too complex. Simplify it first. You're making something like ten method calls, chaining multiple method calls, including a conditional, and including a rescue all in a single line. The error you're showing doesn't help decipher it at all because you haven't included the code for the test, and on top of that you're calling `[]` _four times_ in that one line. Make your life easier: refactor this code into something readable and sensible, _then_ test it.

Comment: I am modifying my code( providing a simpler example).

Comment: @anothermh i just added a different piece of code

Comment: Can you show the failing test, too?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that in the example you gave `rqst` is returning an empty hash `{}`.

When you set `selected_unit_req` it is set to an empty hash:

```
selected_unit_req = rqst.select { |m| select_keys.include?(m) }
=> {}
```

When you subsequently call `selected_unit_req["author"]` the hash is checked for a key named `author`, and this returns `nil`:

```
selected_unit_req["author"]
=> nil
```

So running the full call `selected_unit_req["author"]["username"]` can be seen to be equivalent to the following:

```
nil["username"]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

That's why the error is being raised; you expect `selected_unit_req["author"]` to return a hash with a key `username` but it is instead returning `nil`.

Ensure that `selected_unit_req` has the hash keys and values that you expect first.

**Update**

In the comments below you asked how to verify it has the keys you require. The answer to that depends on a few things, like what behavior you want to see in the event it doesn't have it and the version of Ruby you're using.

I'm going to assume that it's okay to skip `rqst` if it doesn't have the keys and that you're using a modern version of Ruby (>= 2.3.0).

Here's one way to do it using the [`dig`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34348418/3784008) method for the Hash class:

```
request.each do |rqst|
  next unless rqst.dig('author', 'username') && rqst.dig('author', 'name')
  user = Etl::Models::User.where(username: rqst['author']['username'] )
  user.merge!({ author_name: rqst['author']['name'] })
end
```

What we're doing is calling `next` if `rqst` does not have the key `author` with a sub-key named `username` and another sub-key named `name`. This works because `dig` will return `nil` if the hash does not have those keys in it.

Let's pretend for a moment that `rqst == {}`. How that line would be interpreted is:

```
next unless nil && nil
```

Since `nil` is [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068834/what-evaluates-to-false-in-ruby) in Ruby, it ends up calling `next` to skip over the current `rqst` value and move on to the next one in the iteration.

I've also removed `selected_unit_req` because it's unnecessarily repetitive; since you already know exactly what keys/values you want out of `rqst` there is no need to create a new hash with just those values; instead, you can just extract those values and use them directly where needed.

Comment: appreciate your reply, but how do I ensure that? I am very new to ruby so having a lot of trouble figuring this out

Comment: @shitgetsreal I have updated my answer to explain an approach to doing that.